# Написать тест для метода класса, который проверяет делимость на 3

Tags: java, junit

Прошу помощи с задачей.
Есть задача:

Создать тесты для метода checkMultipleOf3 класса Program, который проверяет делимость на 3.
На вход он получает число и возвращает true, если оно делится нацело на 3, и false, если оно не делится на 3 нацело

```
Program program = new Program();
boolean isMultiple3 = program.checkMultipleOf3(<здесь введи число>);
```

Чтобы вызвать метод, использовать эту конструкцию. В переменную isMultiple3 запишется результат теста, который проверяет делимость числа на 3.

Answer (score 0):

Удалось решить задачу. Спасибо тем кто минусовал вопрос :)

Для остальных ребят добавлю код, може будет полезно:

```
@Test
public void checkMultipleOf3True() {
    Program program = new Program();
    boolean isMultiple3 = program.checkMultipleOf3(6);
 
    assertEquals("Ошибка", true, isMultiple3);
}

@Test
public void checkMultipleOf3False() {
    Program program = new Program();
    boolean isMultiple3 = program.checkMultipleOf3(10);
 
    assertEquals("Ошибка", false, isMultiple3);
}
```